# SharePoint Desinger 2013 Customized Workflow cause repeating email

Tags: sharepoint-designer, workflow, email

I customized a workflow in SharePoint Designer 2013 for SP2013, the stage can be transferred normally, but the I got repeating emails, even I add pause for each stage, still the same.
Could anyone help advise how to solve this?[image]

Comment: try to add another stage for exit, for testing perspective